# How to indent html with xmllint?

Tags: html, xmllint

I'm outputting html that's all crushed together, and would like to convert it to have proper indentation. I've been trying to use xmllint for this, but with no joy. E.g. when this is in file.html:

```
<table><tr><td><b>Foo</b></td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Bar</td></tr></table>
```

I get:

```
$ xmllint --format file.html
file.html:2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<table><tr><td>Bar</td></tr></table>
^
<<< exit status [1] >>>
```

But when file.html contains either of those lines alone, it works fine (removing the second line):

```
$ xmllint --format file.html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Foo</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When i inlcude the `--html` option, it's more likely to run without errors, but then it doesn't indent.

Any suggestions? Are there any other (*nix) tools I can use for this? Thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because the HTML you have supplied doesn't have a root tag, thus making it an invalid XML.

Try adding the body tag and run xmllint again on it.

```
<body><table><tr><td><b>Foo</b></td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td>Bar</td></tr></table></body>
```

Answer (score 4):

As user 4M01 suggested: On the command line, append the pipe with a call to HTML tidy.

HTML output from *xmllint* will be repaired; tidy will wrap some reasonable ... around your html fragment.

```
xmllint --xpath "//tr[6]/td[7]" --html - | tidy -q
```

Answer (score 4):

`tidy -i` sets the `indent: auto` config value. If instead of auto I set it to `yes`, I consistently got better indentation style:

```
tidy --indent yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [HTML Tidy](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?download=tidy.zip) ? More Information about this is available at [W3](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) & [sourceforge](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).Even there GUI tool available which known as [GuiTidy](http://www.paehl.de/tidy/gui_tidy_windows.zip) . This tools are great , they not only help  in  proper indentation but also validate html code.

Hope this help